# Accessing Private non-static class variable from Static member function - C++

Tags: c++, oop, private, static-methods

Are private non static variable/methods accessible in static function? If yes,
then what is the use of "Private" access modifier?. Please go through the below code.

```cpp
// Testclassheader.h file
class TestClass{
private:
int TestVariable;    //Private Variable
int TestFunction();   //Private Method

public:
static void TeststaticFn();   //Static Method

};

void TestClass::TeststaticFn()
{
   TestClass TestObj;
   TestObj.TestVariable = 10; // Compiles perfectly
   TestObj.TestFunction(); //Compiles Perfectly

}

// Another Class
//#include "Testclassheader.h"
class AnotherClass{
public:
int DummyFunc();
};

int AnotherClass::DummyFunc()
{
  TestClass AnotherObj;
  AnotherObj.TestVariable = 15; //error: 'TestVariable' is a private member of 'TestClass'
  AnotherObj.TestFunction();    //error: 'TestFunction' is a private member of 'TestClass'
}
```

I tried the above code in Visual studio 12. Can anyone explain why private variable/methods are accessible in static method( which actually it should not)?

Comment: "_Can anyone explain why private variable/methods are accessible in static method( which actually it should not)?_" But you already state, that those lines "`//Throws Error`". So, which is it? Or am I not understanding the question?

Comment: The static function in TestClass is part of TestClass, so has access to the private members of an instance of that class.

Comment: The place it throws error is in another class. This functionality is working fine. Im concerned about the accessing it inside static function.

Comment: `static` means the member function is called without instance - i.e. it doesn't provide `this`. Concerning scope and access rights, it isn't different from non-static functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**All functions** of a given class have access to of that class's `private` members through **any instance**.  You seem to think that `private` limit access to member functions of that particular instance, which is incorrect.

```cpp
class foo
  {
  private:
  int bar;

  // access of the function doesn't matter, but let's use public
  public: 

  // the only case you thought was legal:
  void baz()
    {
    bar = 1;
    }

  // but this is perfectly legal
  void qux(foo otherFoo)
    {
    otherFoo.bar = 1;
    }

  // also legal, as you discovered.
  static void quux(foo iPittyTheFoo)
    {
    iPittyTheFoo.bar = 1;
    }
  };

  class someOtherClass
    {
    // no function here (static or otherwise) has access to baz.

    // UNLESS you "friend someOtherClass" inside class foo.  Whether or not
    // "friend" is ever a good idea is a matter of some debate.
    };

void someGlobalFunction()
  {
  // Also cannot access bar.
  Foo a;
  a.bar = 1; // boom
  }

// nope.  Still cannot access bar.
foo b;
someOtherClass instance(b.bar); // boom
```

Also, "`// throws error`" is misleading.  "Throw" exclusively refers to exception handling, not compile time errors.  Compiler errors, linker errors, and runtime errors are each quite different and require different kinds of problem solving to deal with.  When asking for help from someone not looking at the actual error output, you need to specify which it is.  Just copy-paste-ing the error itself is generally a good idea, then we all have the same information.

In general, I suspect you've misunderstood the purpose of `public:`, `protected:`, and `private:`.  We all had to learn it at some point.

In C++, `public` functions/methods and variables/members (different people use different terms) represent a class's "interface".  These are what everything outside that class is allowed to use.  What goes on behind that interface is none of their business (at least in theory).

`protected` functions and variables are available to classes that inherit from that class.  "Your version of this class may be customized in these ways".

`private` functions and variables are no one else's concern.  No touchy.  As programs change, implementation details within a given class can vary wildly.  The initial implementation of a class might (shudder) return a hardcoded value:

```cpp
  class X 
    {
    ...
    private:
    int Y() { return 1; }
    };
```

Later versions of that same function might look up a value in a database, read from a file, whatever.  "Which database?"  Okay, now we need a parameter...

```
   int Y(WhichDb thisOne) { return thisOne.lookupY(); }
```

So everywhere that was calling Y now needs to pass in a WhichDb (which should probably be a const reference, but that's a whole different topic).  By changing the "function signature" of Y, we have broken all the code that called Y.  In other words, all existing calls to Y are now compiler errors, because they don't pass in a WhichDb.  In one sense, public/protected/private define just how much code a given change will affect/break.

Private?  Just that class.  No problem, I'm responsible for that class (because I can change it's header), so fixing that is no problem.

Protected?  That class, plus everything that inherits from it.  This could easily Break Someone Else's Code, which is generally bad.  Breaking code you're not responsible for is a great way to lose customers.

Public?  Anyone, anywhere could have called that function.  "Breaking changes" to public interfaces are to be avoided.

So maybe your class is only ever used inside you company, in your department, by you.  Public changes at that point are no big deal.  On the other hand, Some Popular Library really cannot do that.  I mean... they COULD, but they'd probably piss off lots of folks.

There are ways to change your public interface without breaking existing code.  You can add new functions, you can add new parameters to existing functions THAT HAVE DEFAULTS: `void foo(int bar = 2);`.  People who called `foo()` will still compile (and hopefully will still get the same behavior they depended on), but now people can call `foo(3)` to get new behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. I was in the thought that the Static Function is similar to any other global function that is visible/transparent to other class. if that is the case, my notion was that the private variables/methods are vulnerable inside static function.

Answer (score 4):

> Are private non static variable/methods accessible in static function?

Yes, private non static variable/methods are accessible by a static function that is part of the self-same class.

> If yes, then what is the use of "Private" access modifier?

It prevents other classes from accessing the private class members and private instance members of the class.

> Can anyone explain why private variable/methods are accessible in static method?

Because all the parts of a class are part of the class.

> which actually [private variable/methods] should not [be accessible to static methods of the same class])?

That is incorrect.